# For what $f$ is $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(2nx)dx\geq 0 ~~\forall n\in\mathbb Z$

Tags: analysis

I have $f$ is positive, even, $2\pi$ periodic and continuous function on $\mathbb R$. Let $a_n=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cos(2nx)dx.$

Is $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ ?

I tried in many ways, but not able to prove or disprove.

Please help me!

Comment: I think is not hard to find a countarexample

Comment: See the special case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem#Special_cases of Bochner's Theorem to help come up with conditions under which all Fourier coefficients of a function $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ are real and nonnegative.  Yours is not exactly that, since you require only half of the Fourier coefficients to be nonnegaive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Lets consider $f(x)=  π^3-(x - \pi)^2 $ on $[0,2\pi]$ we have that
$$
a_1=\int_0^{2π}( π^3-(x - π)^2) cos(2x) dx = -\pi<0 $$.

Comment: But my function is strictly positive, here the function takes zero on some points

Comment: I think adding some positive number with f will work.